# Escaped Backslash Characters in PHP Single Quoted Strings

Tags: php

I took these sentences from the PHP manual:

```
'this is a simple string',
'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"',
'You deleted C:\\*.*?',
'You deleted C:\*.*?',
'This will not expand: \n a newline',
'Variables do not $expand $either'
```

I would like to echo them using PHP code, exactly as they appear, with escaped single quotes (like in the second sentence) and double backslashes (like in the third sentence). This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$strings = array(
        'this is a simple string',
        'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"',
        'You deleted C:\\*.*?',
        'You deleted C:\*.*?',
        'This will not expand: \n a newline',
        'Variables do not $expand $either');

$patterns = array('~\\\'~', '~\\\\~');
$replacements = array('\\\\\'', '\\\\\\\\');

foreach($strings as $string)
{
        echo '\'' . preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string) . '\'' . '</br>';
}
?>
```

The output is:

```
'this is a simple string'
'Arnold once said: "I\\'ll be back"'
'You deleted C:\\*.*?'
'You deleted C:\\*.*?'
'This will not expand: \\n a newline'
'Variables do not $expand $either'
```

but I would like to echo the strings exactly as they are listed in my code if possible. I am having trouble with double backslash characters (\). My second pattern ('~\\~') seems to replace both single and double backslashes. I also tried using addcslashes() with the same results.

(I have asked this question elsewhere recently but without a solution)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might just not be possible. I don't know if it's so but I assume PHP doesn't store the original format of the string, only the content. In that case there's no way to make a difference between sentences #3 and #4 in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of meddling with `preg_replace()`, consider using `var_export()` to print a "true copy" of the string:

```
foreach ($strings as $s) {
    echo var_export($s, true), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
'this is a simple string'
'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"'
'You deleted C:\\*.*?'
'You deleted C:\\*.*?'
'This will not expand: \\n a newline'
'Variables do not $expand $either'
```

As you can see, sentence 3 and 4 are identical to PHP.

Comment: That still leaves me with one extra backslash in the third sentence, but it seems this is as close as you can get. Thanks to all that answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It is working as expected.

```
 <?php

$strings = array(
    'this is a simple string',
    'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"',
    'You deleted C:\\*.*?',
    'You deleted C:\*.*?',
    'This will not expand: \n a newline',
    'Variables do not $expand $either');

 $patterns = array('~\\\'~', '~\\\\~');
 $replacements = array('\\\\\'', '\\\\\\\\');

 foreach($strings as $string){
    print_r(strip_tags($string,"\n,:/"));
    print_r("\n");
 }
?>
```

You can specify allowable_tags in strip_tags. Refer [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for further understanding
Here is [DEMO](http://codepad.org/rdc7AzXL)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to output the strings exactly as they are, ie. enclosed in single quotes and with all the characters that input strings have. So I need two backslashes in the third sentence and in the second sentence the text should contain "I\'ll be back" (with a backslash).