# Testing if PHP Variable contains a Nowdoc String

Tags: php

Is there a way to tell if a PHP variable contains a nowdoc string?

I recently posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918924/escaped-backslash-characters-in-php-single-quoted-strings) question.

My goal is to output PHP strings exactly as they are and I discovered that using nowdoc strings is the closest thing to verbatim strings in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Nowdoc` is not a type of string but a type of quoting. The variable content will be the same regardless of the type of quoting you decide to use.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible. A string is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Once a string is assigned to a variable, PHP has no history of how it got there.