# PHP json_decode a json_encoded string

Tags: php, regex

I don't really get the following...

```
// array to encode
$a = ['regex' => '\/\+\/'];

// decoding an encoded array works
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($a), true));

// encoded array
echo json_encode($a);

// trying to decode the before encoded string doesn't work
print_r(json_decode('{"regex":"\\\/\\+\\\/"}', true));
echo json_last_error_msg();
```

The last error message says `Syntax error`. Shouldn't I be able to easily decode a simple encoded string?

I know that the problem is in the backslashes but I won't want to do any magic string replacement or regex to get the decoding working. Just want to understand where goes what wrong and what's a best practice for this kind of situations?

I'm using PHP version 5.5.9

Comment: Hmm. At same php version I've got `invalid string sequence` error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found something thanks to that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929508/1685538

If instead of taking the string outputted by `echo`, you use `var_export(json_encode($a));` ([documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)), it gives you `{"regex":"\\\\\\/\\\\+\\\\\\/"}`

`print_r(json_decode('{"regex":"\\\\\\/\\\\+\\\\\\/"}', true));` gives the expected result :

```
Array
(
    [regex] => \/\+\/
)
```

with no errors.

Comment: If it is all you needed,  please consider accepting an answer @va5ja

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using backslashes in **PHP code string literals** is subject to PHP's backslash escaping rules. You need to additionally escape the backslashes so they are preserved inside the PHP string:

```
print_r(json_decode('{"regex":"\\\\\\/\\\\+\\\\\\/"}', true));
```

Contrast with:

```
echo '{"regex":"\\\/\\+\\\/"}'; 
//    {"regex":"\\/\+\\/"}
```